# Visual C++ versus standard c++

Tags: visual-c++

1) I have been working with standard C++ (CodeBLocks)and starting to move to Visual C++. When creating a console application the VS builds the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

This is not the standard c++ syntax but windows version.
Now, is there a way to use the standard c++ syntax in Visual Studio C++ and avoid the above
sintax so as to use the standard?

I mean, using VS C++ be able to code something standard such as:

```
#include "<iostream.h>"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{
    int month, day, year;

    cout << "Hellow World" << endl;




    return 0;
}
```

2) I get in visual c++ error by trying to include very common libraries such as 
`#include "<iostream.h>"`. Any advise much appreciated. (using VS 2013 and comparing it with previous code in WnDEv).

3) I also attemted to use this with an empty project adding:
but when I build it InteliSense cannot open source file stdafx.h, IntelliSense identifier "cout" is undefined, IntelliSense identifier "cin" is undefined. Please help. thank you

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    //clrscr();
    int number, count = 0;
    cout << "ENTER NUMBER TO CHECK IT IS PRIME OR NOT ";
    cin >> number;
    for (int a = 1; a <= number; a++)
    {
        if (number%a == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 2)
    {
        cout << " PRIME NUMBER \n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " NOT A PRIME NUMBER \n";
    }
    //getch();
}
```

Comment: You do know that `<iostream.h>` was deprecated in the C++03 specification? You should be using `<iostream>` (without the `.h` suffix).

Comment: Also, doing `#include "<iostream>"` will most likely not work very well. You *either* use `<header>` *or* `"header"`.

Comment: I hope you are also including "stdafx.h" on top of your source file, above the <iostream>

Comment: These are just macros, they produce the "standard version" depending on your project settings.  Otherwise an attempt from Microsoft to help you not ignore Unicode.  You certainly can ignore it if you want to, this is just minimal auto-generated code that you can delete and replace with your own.

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion of `"stdafx.h"` is because Visual C++ by default uses [pre-compiled headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header), and for that to work the first non-comment line in the source file have to be that inclusion.

For the `_tmain` function, it tells me you have opted to make a WIN32 console project. You can make an empty project, and add files manually as needed, and use only standard C++ features, like having the proper `main` function instead.